# How to make a while loop with 2 conditions?

Tags: python, while-loop

I want to check if the variable "type" equal "video", "audio" or a wrong type with a while loop but it isn't working with 2 conditions. When I put only 'while type != "video":' it works perfectly but when I add the 'or type!= "audio":' it stops to work can you help me to fix it please?

```
type = input("Do you want a video or an audio? (answer by video or audio) \n >> ")
while type != "video" or type!= "audio":
    print('Error! select an existing type')
    type = input("Do you want a video or an audio? (answer by video or audio) \n >> ")
if type == "video":
    video_dwld()
elif type == "audio":
    audio_dwld()
```

Comment: As a programmer you need to be aware of [De Morgan''s laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws)

Comment: Did you mean: `while type != "video" and type!= "audio":`?

Comment: Usual English grammar does not always work for programming languages. We have no way to distinguish between "or" and "xor" in English language, but that's what you want here. (Same for German) Since we don't have an `xor` keyword either, we end up using `and` and `not`.

Comment: Even better: `while type not in {"video", "audio"}:`. But you really shouldn't name your variable `type` because you overwrite the built-in [`type`](https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/functions.html#type) now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @quamrana commented, almost, it seems that you're looping while `type` is not equal to one of the supported values.

It is *always* not equal to one of the supported values, since it's at most equal to a single one of them.

Hint: use the power of Python:

```py
supported_types = ("audio", "video")
while media_type not in supported_types:
    media_type = input(...)
```

Another hint: it's easier to ask for forgiveness than for permission: use a `dict` to structure the handlers, and use `try/except` to deal with errors.

```py
handlers = {
    "audio": audio_dwld,
    "video": video_dwld
}


while True:
    try:
        media_type = input(...)
        handle = handlers[media_type]
        handle()
    except KeyError:
        print("a useful error message") 
    else:
        break
```